# Rails association is nil in the after_initialize callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I have a model named Purchase with a field named tickets and amount. This model belongs to Event, which has a price. I want to call update_amount callback after a new Purchase is created, but in the callback method the associated event doesn't seem to exist.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  attr_accessible :event_id, :tickets, :amount
  delegate :price, to: :event
  after_initialize :update_amount
  ...
  def update_amount
   update_attribute :amount, self.tickets * self.price
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price
  ...
end
```

When I test it, though, I came across the following:

```
$ Purchase.new(tickets: 2, event_id: 1541)  
RuntimeError: Purchase#price delegated to event.price, but event is nil: <Purchase
id: nil, user_id: nil, event_id: nil, amount: nil, tickets: 1,
event_date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, checkout_id: nil,
checkout_uri: nil, state: "incomplete">
```

Note that there is an event in the system with the id 1541, but ActiveRecord doesn't have access to that? I tried the same thing without delegate, using event.price, and the same thing happened, i.e. got a price is not found for NilClass error.

Can anyone help me make sense of this? Is the association not formed in the `after_initialize` block? Is there something I'm overlooking?

---

PS: I ended up adding a guard into the callback so it doesn't get invoked if the Event is nil. This is just a hack, though, and it'd be great to get to the bottom of this problem sometime.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm tackling a similar problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find

after_initialize is like a constructor for the Ruby object -- it's called before any database information is loaded into that object.

What you probably want is a :before_save callback to set the amount based on the tickets and price.  In essence, "Before I save myself, recalculate my amount based on my current number of tickets and the price of those tickets.  Then, write me to the database."

Comment: Sometimes AR objects are created but not persisted for the form rendering. `before_save` won't cover this scenario.